# CallByName not returning value for certain types

Tags: vba, excel, callbyname

I am having a problem with the CallByName function. I am trying to split up a collection into smaller collections depending on the value of a property, and then assigning those smaller collections to an array.

The section of code works below is the bit that is causing the problem. Whenever X refers to a property that contains a string value the code works fine, but whenever I try and pass CallByName a property with the type double it doesn't fetch it properly (I think).

```
Dim temp as Variant

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Set collSplit = New Collection
    For Each v In collTruck
        temp = CallByName(v, X, VbGet)    ''''''''
        If temp = arr(i, 1) Then          ''''''''
            collSplit.Add v
            arr(i, 2) = arr(i, 2) + 1
        End If
    Next v
    Set arr(i, 3) = collSplit
Next i
```

Originally I just had `If CallByName(v, X, VbGet) = arr(i, 1) Then` but I added the `temp` line to help with debugging.

Putting break points on the two commented lines shows that when X refers to a property with type double temp is always kept empty. But in the Immediate window if I try `? CallByName(v, X, VbGet)` it gives me the value I am looking for. Why is the value for `CallByName(v, X, VbGet)` only being received in the Immediate window?

Comment: How/where is `temp` declared?

Comment: In the sub just above this code, just edited to show that

Comment: I can't think of any reason for it to work without `temp` but not with. Can you put an actual file somewhere that shows this problem?

Comment: It doesn't work either with or without `temp` if the type isn't string. I'll have to edit it first, got a bit of sensitive info on, but should be okay. A link on Dropbox okay?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. `CallByName` does work with properties that return Doubles.

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/70627iz4cj94n4y/stackoverflow_version.xlsm?dl=0
Only started using VBA a couple of weeks ago so excuse the shoddy programming

Comment: Code works as expected here (though what you posted is not actually in that file). Where specifically are you seeing the problem?

Comment: Fixed it! Found out that the values in the array were being stored as strings somehow (even though they were being called by `CallByName` as well) so when you evaluated `If temp = arr(i, 1)` it always returned `False` because `temp` was a double. Thanks for your help @Rory!